# Does something like a fast LaTeX syntax checker for checking errors / warnings exist?

Tags: tools, syntax-checker

When I currently compile my LaTeX document, I do it like this:

```
sketch figures/torus.sketch > figures/torus.tex
pdflatex $(DOKUMENT).tex -output-format=pdf # aux-files for makeindex / makeglossaries
makeindex $(DOKUMENT)
pdflatex $(DOKUMENT).tex -output-format=pdf # include index
pdflatex $(DOKUMENT).tex -output-format=pdf # include symbol table
make clean # remove intermediate files like *.log and *.aux
```

This takes about 245 seconds (over 4 minutes).

But quite often, when I compile the document the first time after many changes, it has some errors, e.g.

- forgetting about LaTeX issues with `#` and `_`
- forgetting curly braces `{` or `}`
- confusing `input{figures/somefile.tex}` with `\includegraphics{figures/somefile.png}`
- forgetting to include packages

It would really be awesome if there was a fast LaTeX syntax checker. I would let the syntax checker run before the rest. If it fails, the rest will not be executed (as I do it with a `Makefile`, make will stop when the first error occurs). **Does a LaTeX syntax checker exist?** (False-negatives are ok, but there should not be any false-positives).

Comment: If I'm not wrong you can test the result of each command. For example, if everything was fine with `pdflatex` the value of `$?` will be zero.

Comment: @Sigur: I'm not sure, but I think you did not understand my question. This is not a question about `make`, but about `pdflatex`. I want it to fail (if it fails) as soon as possible. Currently, it happens often that it compiles 3 minutes and then fails because of a missing `}`.

Comment: Does `pdflatex -draftmode` do what you want? It cuts away the output phase, but does all the rest.

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53771/15925 answer your question?

Comment: Maybe `pdflatex -halt-on-error` or `-interaction=errorstopmode.`

Comment: @AndrewSwann: No, most of the time I know where to search for the error. I just want to get an information that there is an error sooner.

Comment: @egreg: I think so. I've just added an error to my document and test how fast it fails. I'll add a comment in 10 minutes or so.

Comment: I was thinking mostly of the `syntonly` package mentioned in at least one solution there.

Comment: I use `pdflatex -halt-on-error foo.tex 1> /dev/null
[[ $? -eq 1 ]] && echo "Error with pdflatex. Check TeX files." && exit` on my script.

Comment: @egreg: Neither `pdflatex -halt-on-error` nor `pdflatex -interaction=errorstopmode` nor adding `-draftmode` made it fail faster.

Comment: Four minutes?! How long is your document?

Comment: @Jubobs: about 100 A4 pages; 8330 lines of Tex (I guess about 100 TikZ images).

Comment: @moose, many `tikz` code could make the process slower.

Comment: @Sigur: Yes, it certainly does. But I don't see a good alternative. I could use PDFs, but that would probably change the size of the included image (especially the size of texts within the included TikZ images).

Comment: @moose Have you considered using `standalone` for the images? If they are slowing things down, putting them in external files and using `standalone` should speed compilation significantly because you wouldn't have to recompile the `tikz` code for all pictures each time.

Comment: You could externalize the TikZ graphics, that could save time. See chapter 32 *Externalization library* in the manual.