# Macros in TeXStudio

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

I noticed in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44206/help-me-to-write-long-latex-equations-fast-with-colours-and-possibly-with-other/44214#44214), when the user hits `((` what actually generates in the editor is `\left( \right)`, where the cursor is positioned between the first parenthesis and before `\right`.

How does one do this with TeXStudio?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Go to Macros -> Edit Macros ...` and add a new entry:

[image]

Notes:

- The slashes in the trigger are necessary, because it's a regexp.
- You may want to disable `Configure -> Advanced Editor -> Special Options -> Auto Complete Parentheses`. Otherwise, you'll have an additional ) from the auto completion of the first (. Alternatively, you could switch the type from Normal to Script, and use

  ```js
  cursor.deleteChar()
  editor.write("\\left(")
  ```

  to delete the additionally inserted )
- You can add a similar macro one for ))

Comment: You should probably move the cursor back after `editor.write`...

Comment: valuable answer! really helps

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Tim's answer, using script may be advantageous because it still allows auto completion of single parenthesis. Do typing `((` using the following

```js
cursor.deleteChar()
editor.write("\\left\(  \\right\)")
cursor.movePosition(8,cursorEnums.Left)
```

will put the cursor between `\left` and `\right`.