# In texstudio: a list of inline maths expressions?

Tags: texstudio

I find, when I write about a a subject, that I need to write the same bits of inline-maths over and over, and I end up copying from earlier in the text, which is tiresome. Having a list on the left, like the 'Most used symbols', containing all the bits of $...$ stuff used in the text would be really handy. Is there a way to get that in texstudio?

Comment: I have no idea about texstudio but you can always use tex for such things: `\newcommand\fermat{$a^n+b^n=c^n$}`   means you just need `\fermat` not copying the inline math each time.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that is workable, although infinitesimally more work :-) Thx!

Comment: You could use macros like in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113089/237192 in order to save some time