# finding missing citation biblatex

Tags: citing, biber

I am working toward completing my book in xelatex and biber. The book has a master file and various chapters in different files. 
As I am correcting the final draft and creating the index before the final printing and reading, somewhere I forgot a round bracket after a series of citations, using \cites:

The Biber output (.bbl) complains:

```
 Running `Biber' on `PSAMMETICHUSII' with ``biber PSAMMETICHUSII''
 INFO - This is Biber 2.2
 INFO - Logfile is 'PSAMMETICHUSII.blg'
 INFO - Reading 'PSAMMETICHUSII.bcf'
 INFO - Found 848 citekeys in bib section 0
 INFO - Processing section 0
 INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'PsammetichusII_biber.bib' for section 0
 INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
 INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'PsammetichusII_biber.bib'
 WARN - I didn't find a database entry for '(' (section 0)
 INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
 INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
 INFO - Sorting list 'shorthand' of type 'list' with scheme 'shorthand' and locale 'en-US'
 INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-US'
 INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
 INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
 INFO - Sorting list 'nty' of type 'entry' with scheme 'nty' and locale 'en-US'
 INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-US'
 INFO - Writing 'PSAMMETICHUSII.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
 INFO - Output to PSAMMETICHUSII.bbl
 INFO - WARNINGS: 1
```

As section 0 simply refers to the Master file, but it does not tell me precisely where the citation is missing, a simple round bracket somewhere. I have even checked the resulting .bcf, but is does not help much either.

I tried to go through the files in order to find out the bracket, surely the result of some corrections, but is there a simple way to find out missing entries in a multifile LaTeX project?

I am using aquamacs and MacTeX 2015 if this might help.

Comment: Looks like you have something like `\cite{(...}` in your first section

Comment: Put some \refsection commands in the document, then you can see in which refsection the problem is.

Comment: @Ulrike Fisher Thanks for the suggestion. Does it mean that I put a \refsection command in each file composing the book apart from Master File?

Comment: Whereever you want. There are only for the debugging to help you to identify the location of problematic \cite.

Comment: Another way of finding the offending parenthesis would be one of the solutions in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6470/is-there-a-package-for-warning-about-unbalanced-delimiters

Comment: You can use a text editor like notepad++. There's a function that allows you to search for strings in many files at once. Just search for **{(**.

Comment: I'm more inclined to look for `\cite(`.

Comment: In the end, I have deleted all the outputs file and let xelatexmk run again. Looking at the output, I found that the offending citation was in chapter two: Just for information, the wrong citation format was of such a genre: \cites(IV/2)[955 (935){JansenWinkeln.2007}. Yes, there was a missing square bracket. I tried to put the\refsection in the masterfile, after each chapter input, such as \introduction \refsection; \chapterone \refsection  in a new line, but it was complaining of nested citation parts. I have to check \refsection better

Answer (score 1):

Just some screenshots to my comment:

> You can use a text editor like [Notepad++](http://www.heise.de/download/notepad-portable.html). There's a function that
>   allows you to search for strings in many files at once. In your case try to  search
>   for `{(` or `\cite(` as suggested in the comments.

### Search --> Find in Files

[image]

### Look for your string (e. g. `\cite(`) in your dictionary (including sub-folders if necessary)

[image]